# rsyslog: log message from remote host to specific file

Tags: server, logging, rsyslog

I am trying to log messages from a specific remote host to a separate log file (and only to that file). I tried this:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/avs110door.conf 

if $fromhost == 'avs110' then /var/log/avs110-door.log
& stop
```

The log file is not created, and the messages form that host are still sent to user.log, syslog, messages and auth.log (depending on the facility).

I did run `systemctl restart rsyslog.service` and other .conf files from that directory do work as expected.

This is a server with rsyslog version 8.4.2

The messages in the wrong files are like this (so the remote hostname is indeed 'avs110' as in my .conf file condition):

```
Jul 18 18:27:19 avs110 sshd[781]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 18 18:27:39 avs110 engine[844]: Finished initialization
Jul 18 18:44:20 avs110 engine[844]: Calling sip:600@192.168.44.152:5060
```

Comment: There are two different reasons: First, as the rules in `rsyslog.conf` preceed the rules in `rsyslog.d/`, the default rules do match and so the entries are written to the facility logs. If you do not want that, youl'd have to write additional discard rules in your configuration file (see 'Discard' in the manpage of rsyslog.conf). Second, as far as I remember, syslog files are only written to if they already exist; so try `sudo touch /var/log/avs110-door.log` to see if will be filled up (maybe you have to change the owner to syslog:adm).

Comment: @ridgy I have a configuration similar to the above, without  an additional `Discard` rule; all my rules are in a separate config file in `/etc/rsyslog.d`. Still, this rule works. Your second point is valid however; I need to `touch` the file for the rule to work.

Comment: The [documentation]( http://www.rsyslog.com/storing-messages-from-a-remote-system-into-a-specific-file/) suggests to define the remote rules _before_ the local rules and to stop proceeding by defining `& ~` (Discard). Maybe that helps.

Comment: @ridgy: I have `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` before the default rules in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, so that should be OK. Created the log file with `touch` now, and will see in a day or 2 if that was it. (I guess yes)

Comment: Turns out that the value of `$fromhost` must be something other than the hostname written to the log. Replacing it with `$fromhost-ip` and the correct IP, it works.